# I am trying to set up easycron

Tags: wordpress, cron, scheduled-job

I am trying to set up easy cron and everythingI am seeing says:

name=username&pass=password&key=site-key

Am I suppose to substitute my wordpress username and password for this?  What is the site-key?

Answer (score 2):

The username and password are for a WordPress user.  I would recommend setting up a user specifically for this purpose and don't use it for anything else.

You will need to give the user the correct permissions:

- View all contacts
- Access CiviCRM
- Access CiviMail

Please see the documentation for more details: [Scheduled jobs](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/)

You will need to set the site key in the civicrm.settings.php file - see: [Site key](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/site-key/)